# Recieve two different height of keyboard after rotation

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsnotificationcenter

I have a view which is resize a constraint when the keyboard appear. So I have notifications when the keyboard appears and disappears.

The above behaviour occurs when the keyboard is already shown and I rotate the screen. Then the next actions occurs:

1. UIKeyboardWillHideNotification called
2. UIKeyboardWillShowNotification called (with the old height of the keyboard)
3. UIKeyboardWillShowNotification called (with the new height of the keyboard)

So, the updateView function receives first one height and later a different height. This results in a weird movements of the view adjusting twice the value.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Creates notification when keyboard appears and disappears
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

}

deinit {

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    self.adjustingHeight(true, notification: notification)

}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

    self.adjustingHeight(false, notification: notification)

}

private func adjustingHeight(show: Bool, notification: NSNotification) {

    // Gets notification information in an dictionary
    var userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    // From information dictionary gets keyboard’s size
    let keyboardFrame:CGRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
    // Gets the time required for keyboard pop up animation
    let animationDurarion = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSTimeInterval
    // Animation moving constraint at same speed of moving keyboard & change bottom constraint accordingly.
    if show {
        self.bottomConstraint.constant = (CGRectGetHeight(keyboardFrame) + self.bottomConstraintConstantDefault / 2)
    } else {
        self.bottomConstraint.constant = self.bottomConstraintConstantDefault
    }
    UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDurarion) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    self.hideLogoIfSmall()

}
```

Comment: Not very sure, but maybe can add another observation for "UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification" and deal with height in its selector?

Comment: @Allen I thinks I would be in the same situation. I would have to deal with height in UIKeyboardWillShowNotification and UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification is called twice with different heights as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. When I get `keyboardFrame`, I was using `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` which returns the frame of the keyboard before the animation begins. The correct way of do that is with `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`which returns the frame of the keyboard after the animation has completed.

```
let keyboardFrame: CGRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
```

Comment: Was struggling with the keyboard animation for a whole day. This solution solved it. Thanks!